# WebDriverAgent folder missing appium 1.15.1

Tags: appium

I have installed appium 1.15.1 to mac catalina 10.15.2. I couldn't find WebDriverAgent folder inside appium-xcuitest-driver.

Answer (score 0):

if webedriveragent missing from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/

Tye reinstalling appium globally.

1.npm uinstall -g appium
2.npm install -g appium

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

In **Appium 1.15.0 and above** appium-webdriveragent is available on below path

cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver agent path :
/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).